# Calling firebase.auth().currentUser works but produces error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Tags: firebase

Throughout my code, I occasionally need to check if there is a user logged in, or get the email/user ID of the user.

My code works fine, but I get a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404" error which is annoying since I log all errors.

I initialize Firebase like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import 'firebase/compat/functions'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/analytics'
import 'firebase/compat/database'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

var admin = firebase

const firebaseConfig = {
//Removed
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Then I get the current user like this:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
```

Again the code works, but I still get an error. I thought it was because firebase is returning a promise, but I tried putting it in a function with async and await like this, but there was no difference.

```
async function testFunction() {
const user = await firebase.auth().currentUser
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What was the URL associated with the 404? Which JS variant is this for (browser/node/etc)? Where is this code being deployed?

Comment: The url looks like this (I replaced the domain name and shorted the apiKey but you can see the overall format). It's being loaded in a browser with vanilla JS and is being deployed locally with npm run dev using Parcel as a package bundler.

https://mydomainishere.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=AIzaSyAd8S8dkam9RuCftv7s&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=9.1.3&eid=p&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.-F_i8pxym_s.O%2Fam%3DAQ%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%t_7PICWuDXqniQ%2Fm%3D__features__#id=I0_1639157160091&_gfid=I0_1639157160091&parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1234&pfname=&rpctoken=41271429

Comment: `/__` path prefixes are internal Firebase Hosting routes and handle things like authentication handshakes, (optionally) initializing the web SDK and processing email action links. Is the domain you are accessing hosted on Firebase Hosting? When you are running your code via `npm run dev`, are you using the Firebase emulators or serving the content directly?